# Goutte Scrape Login to https Secure Website

Tags: symfony, ssl, curl, web-scraping, goutte

So I'm trying to use Goutte to login to an *https* website but I get the following error:

`cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate 
500 Internal Server Error - RequestException 
1 linked Exception: RingException`

And this is the code that the creator of Goutte says to use:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://github.com/');
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('login' => 'fabpot', 'password' =>     'xxxxxx'));
$crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```

OR here's come code that Symfony recommends:

```
use Goutte\Client;

// make a real request to an external site
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');

// select the form and fill in some values
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Log in')->form();
$form['login'] = 'symfonyfan';
$form['password'] = 'anypass';

// submit that form
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

The thing is that neither of them work, I get the error that I posted above. I *CAN*, however log in using the code written in this past question I've asked: [cURL Scrape then Parse/Find Specific Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747006/curl-scrape-then-parse-find-specific-content/28747970)

I just want to use Symfony/Goutte to login in, so that scraping the data I need will be easier. Any help or suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Read about SSL Certificate problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following to the code fixes the error (curl configuration):

```
    // make a real request to an external site
    $client = new Client();
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');
```

But then another error occurs:

```
The current node list is empty.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

Once again, I'm using Goutte with Symfony and default code to do a test task, such as logging into https github.

The fix for the previous error about `node list empty` is that the Github login page button actually says "Sign in" and not *Submit* or *Login* on the button. Unfortunately, the Goutte api isn't clear as to if `$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();` refers to the html `name` attribute or the actual plain text of the button. It's obviously the plain text; slightly confusing. So after more research of a poorly documented api, I ended with the following code that works:

```
// make a real request to an external site
$client = new Client();
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');

// select the form and fill in some values
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
$form['login'] = 'symfonyfan';
$form['password'] = 'anypass';

// submit that form
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
echo $crawler->html();
```